# Dynamic src for img tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, svg, src

I have a react-app that gets crypto **API** from some Provider Server and **setState** in **currency** variable and shows them in a table.
I download each cryptocurrency icon and create a JSON file (cryptoIconSrc) to set **img tag** **src** dynamically.
icons are SVG.
but they don't **display** on my table.

here I set a condition to find the related icon from the JSON file

```
currency.map((item) => {
                    let mapItem = item;
                    const temp = cryptoIconSrc.filter((item) => {
                      return item["symbol"] === mapItem["baseAsset"];
                    });
```

and here I set that related icon to img src

```
                    <img
                    src={`${temp[0]["src"]}`}
                    width="20px"
                    height="20px"
                    />
```

but they don't display

I use `require("./someDirectory/icon.png")` in other sections of my app
but in this case `` require(`${temp[0]["src"]}`) `` doesn't work and issue an error : module ... not found

Answer (score 0):

```
  <img
    src={`${temp[0]["src"]}`}
    key={`${temp[0]["src"]}`}
    width="20px"
    height="20px"
   />
```

Adding a key prop will do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like you are using back ticks in your code. That almost never works, try using single quotes. So not:

```
src={`${temp[0]["src"]}`}
```

But:

```
src={'${temp[0]["src"]}'}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals